# Remove line breaks without making spans blocks

Tags: css

Is there any CSS property/solution to prevent the need of a `<br>` between every `<span>`?

For example, instead of having:

```
  HTML
<span>a</span>
<br>
<span>b</span>
<br>
<span>c</span>
```

Have something like this:

```
  CSS
span{break-line:true}

  HTML
<span>a</span>
<span>b</span>
<span>c</span>
```

I know I can use `display:block` but I don't want to change the span's size.
One example to why that would be bad is color the background of the span.

Comment: As @Yousaf says, better to pick an element that is block by default.

Comment: I feel dumb, why is no one suggesting `span {
  display: block;
}`?

Comment: @Goose read the last line of the question

Comment: @j08691, ah, missed that part somehow

Answer (score 2):

You can use float and clear on them:

```css
span {
float: left;
clear: both;
background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<span>a</span>
<span>b</span>
<span>c</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `:after` pseudo-element with `white-space: pre;`

```css
span:after {
  content: '\A'; /* a newline */
}
span {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<span>a</span>
<span>b</span>
<span>c</span>
```

Comment: Best answer. Unlike Johannes' answer, and other alternatives like applying `display:table` to the span, this won't cause a latent width property to start applying to the span.